# Linux: Split columns of file into multiple files

Tags: python, linux, perl

Whats the best (easiest?) way to take a large file that has many columns (~600000) and split it into 6 files with evenly spread out columns among the 6 files? Also, I want each file to have the first 6 columns from original file

example:

```
 FID     IID     MID     PID     SEX     PHENO   SNP1    SNP2    SNP3    SNP4
 1       70323   0       0       2       2       0       0       1       0    ...
 2       70323   0       0       2       2       1       0       2       1    ...
 3       70323   0       0       2       2       0       0       0       1    ...
 ...
```

Solutions using basic linux command line functions available to ubuntu would be preferable (or perl/python script)

My solution in PERL:
Here is what I did in Perl. Its very ugly so I was hoping there would be a simple elegant solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $line;
my $num_snps=0;
my $i=0;

my $OUT1;
my $OUT2;
my $OUT3;
my $OUT4;

my $end1;
my $end2;
my $end3;
my $end4;
while($line = <>){
        chomp $line;
        my @a = split(/\s/,$line);
        if($i==0){
                $num_snps = $#a + 1 - 6;

                $end1 = 5+int($num_snps/4);
                $end2 = $end1+int($num_snps/4)+1;
                $end3 = $end2+int($num_snps/4)+1;
                $end4 = $#a;

                print("Breaks: $end1\t$end2\t$end3\t$end4\tTotal SNPs: $num_snps\n");
        }else{
                open($OUT1 , ">>kuehn1.raw");
                print $OUT1 join(" ",@a[0..5])." ".join(" ", @a[6..$end1])."\n";
                close($OUT1);
                open($OUT2 , ">>kuehn2.raw");
                print $OUT2 join(" ",@a[0..5])." ".join(" ", @a[($end1+1)..$end2])."\n";
                close($OUT2);
                open($OUT3 , ">>kuehn3.raw");
                print$OUT3 join(" ",@a[0..5])." ".join(" ", @a[($end2+1)..$end3])."\n";
                close($OUT3);
                open($OUT4 , ">>kuehn4.raw");
                print$OUT4 join(" ",@a[0..5])." ".join(" ", @a[($end3+1)..$end4])."\n";
                close($OUT4);
        }
        $i=$i+1;
}
```

Comment: If you downvoted...can you explain why so I can improve my question?

Comment: You're just asking for a ready-to-use solution, and show no research effort / attempt to solve the problem yourself. See [SO question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Do you have an option of changing the delimiter let say to pipe "|"?

Comment: What do you mean by "evenly spread out" exactly, and why on earth do you want to do this?

Comment: @LukasGraf sorry for the lack of detail. I was only familiar with how to cut columns from a file using linux cut, but wasn't sure how to get how many columns there were in the file

Comment: @RobinGreen Reason to do this is to run a program in parallel on the split up file instead of on the single concatenated file

Comment: @RobinGreen by "evenly spread out" i mean if there were 60 columns then file1 would get 10 columns, file2 would get the next 10 columns...etc

Comment: @Benjamin Much better! Flagged for re-opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first get the number of columns in the file with

```
awk '{ print NF}' < file
```

then use that knowledge to construct your breakpoints. So if your file had 66 columns

```
cut -f1-6,7-16 < file > file1
cut -f1-6,17-26 < file > file2
cut -f1-6,27-36 < file > file3
cut -f1-6,37-46 < file > file4
cut -f1-6,47-56 < file > file5
cut -f1-6,57-66 < file > file6
```

Not most elegant, but should work